# Jade Dynasty - Increase FPS

Tags: performance, jade-dynasty

I have a decent PC
( Core i7 950
10gb DDR3 1600mhz
Zotac GTX 260^2 AMP2 )

Yet the game runs on ~45FPS on the lowest settings. If I look around, it can go down to 15fps.

I'm using the latest NVidia driver and DirectX.
Please let me know if there are hacks, or config options to improve it.

(GPU load is on 1-15% and CPU is on 5%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up what my investigation came up with:
- **The game engine is old, buggy. BAD.** Perfect World Entertainment uses the very same, very old codebase engine for every game of theirs. It's the same with Perfect World and Forsaken World. The engine only uses up to ~30% CPU and ~30% GPU , no matter if you have an Intel, or AMD, or nVidia or ATI ... doesn't matter. It'll lag, even on a Core i7. (I have tried.)
- **Disabling VSYNC** (due to the buggy engine) can make a huge performance increase, HOWEVER, you can burn your PC if it's capable of overheating. (VSYNC keeps the max framerate at your refresh rate, i.e. @60hz/60FPS.)

Aaaand that's it. PWE is not likely to upgrade the engine, so DON'T buy a new PC just for this game.. or any PWE game. Go for a simple monthly-paid MMORPG which is optimized (at least well-written). The money you would save on F2P and your new PC is enough for a few decades of monthly subs and expansions.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to turn antialiasing off.
- Try to use differend drivers or operating system (Windows XP might be faster).
- You can also have low free hard drive space.
- Get the most recent updates and patches. Try to look if there are some issues with patches.
- snow and trees (etc) may cause some peoples pcs to lag

Comment: I doubt Windows XP will be faster than Vista/7, since XP only has up to DirectX 9.

Comment: Well, I have tried all these, and nothing. Guess the engine is simply that bad.